# How to add a style to TextFields in theme provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I added custom transitions and colors for the `textfields` and i can pass it to the component with `makeStyles` hook .

But the problem is every time i want to use the customs i should define it in the component

I want to set it in the theme provider so that it is an static style for all the textfield components

I tried to add in overrides section in the `createMuiTheme`

Here is what i've tried so far (just the relevant part)

```
  const THEME = createMuiTheme({

        overrides:{
            "& label.Mui-focused": {
              color: "white",
            },
            "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
              borderBottomColor: "white",
            },
           }
         return (
               <div>
                 <MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
                   <Header />
                   <MainPage />
                 </MuiThemeProvider>
               </div>
            );
         };
```

Theme provider works fine on the other components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `MuiTextField` element to the `overrides` element to define the style for textfields

```
 const THEME = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiTextField: {
        root:{
        "& label.Mui-focused": {
          color: "white",
        },
```